# how to hide a specific data-type value div using css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to hide a specific div using a css code but it's not working

```
<div class="test" data-type="category">
```

whenever i try to use

```
.test{
display:none;
}
```

it hides the whole test div's, i need to be able to hide the `category` data-type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any element with their attribute by using `element[attribute=value]` in you css.

In your example you can do something like this

```css
.test[data-type="category"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" data-type="category">
Some text.
</div>
```